# How to filter objects from an array of Strings in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of allMenuItems as below, which I am trying to filter from an array of Id's. How is this achievable in Swift? I have some understanding of higher order functions, but so far I've been unable to filter this successfully. Any pointers on how this could be achieved would be welcome, thanks.

```
struct MenuItems {
    var id: String
    var name: String

    init() {
        self.id = ""
        self.name = ""
    }
}

var m1 = MenuItems()
m1.id = "1"
m1.name = "Name 1"

var m2 = MenuItems()
m2.id = "2"
m2.name = "Name 2"

var m3 = MenuItems()
m3.id = "3"
m3.name = "Name 3"

var allMenuItems: [MenuItems] = [m1, m2, m3] // [{id "1", name "Name 1"}, {id "2", name "Name 2"}, {id "3", name "Name 3"}]

var anArrayOfIds: [String] = ["1", "3"]
```

The filtered output would be:

```
var filteredMenuItems: [MenuItems] = [m1, m3] // [{id "1", name "Name 1"}, {id "3", name "Name 3"}]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `var id: String`, `self.id = ""`, This is *really* bad practice in Swift. Don't add mutability where it's not needed, and don't use non-sensical defaults (a name of `""`)

Comment: @Alexander - point taken, thanks. This is not the actual code in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

`let filteredMenuItems = allMenuItems.filter { anArrayOfIds.contains($0.id)}`

That gives me the items with 1 and 3.

I've taken the liberty of updating your code a little:

```
struct MenuItems {
    let id: String
    let name: String
}

let m1 = MenuItems(id: "1", name: "Name 1")
let m2 = MenuItems(id: "2", name: "Name 2")
let m3 = MenuItems(id: "3", name: "Name 3")

let allMenuItems = [m1, m2, m3]
let anArrayOfIds: [String] = ["1", "3"]

let filteredMenuItems = allMenuItems.filter { anArrayOfIds.contains($0.id)}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like so:

```
let filteredMenuItems = allMenuItems.filter { anArrayOfIds.contains($0.id) }
```

---

I would suggest you :

- remove the pointless initializer,
- make `id` an integer,
- if the properties won't be changed after initialization then use `let` instead of `var`,
- make anArrayOfIds a set instead of an array, since the `contains` method would be *O(1)* instead of *O(n)*.

Implementing all of these recommendations gives you the following code:

```
struct MenuItems {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}

let m1 = MenuItems(id: 1, name: "Name 1")
let m2 = MenuItems(id: 2, name: "Name 2")
let m3 = MenuItems(id: 3, name: "Name 3")

let allMenuItems: [MenuItems] = [m1, m2, m3]

var aSetOfIds: Set<Int> = [1, 3]  //I used a var if aSetOfIds could be changed

var filteredMenuItems = allMenuItems.filter { aSetOfIds.contains($0.id) }
```

Comment: As mentioned, this was drafted in a hurry and I've already taken a bashing for it. The id is actually a GUID, and none of this code is actually real per se. Still I guess I will pay in downvotes. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter and contains

```
let filtered = allMenuItems.filter( { anArrayOfIds.contains($0.id) })
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all please don't use a weird syntax in a struct like

```
init() {
     self.id = ""
     self.name = ""
}
```

Delete the `init` method and create items with the implicit memberwise initializer, by the way you should name structs representing a single object in singular form:

```
let m1 = MenuItem(id: "1", name: "Name 1")
```

You can even declare the members as constants

```
struct MenuItem {
    let id, name : String
}
```

And don't annotate types the compiler can infer.

---

Filter the array by another array of `id` values with

```
let filteredMenuItems = allMenuItems.filter{ anArrayOfIds.contains($0.id) }
```

Comment: Yes, apologies. This isn't the actual code and was clubbed together in a hurry. Still, no excuse on my part.